# Neo fields dissapearing

Tags: plugin-neo

I am running Craft 4.3.11 and Neo 3.6.4 (recently upgraded both) and now when i save my Neo field all the child neo blocks dissapear (which in turn makes all my site content dissapear).

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
Malcolm

Comment: Can you update to the latest Craft 4.4.5 and Neo 3.7.5 and see if you can reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Thanks Brad - updated and also increased my max_input_vars - not sure which one it was but is resolved now - thanks for the help

Comment: Awesome - want to add that as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Comment: Brad  - i am an idiot i do not know how to assign an official answer!

Comment: Not at all! You should see a big "Your Answer" text box at the bottom of this page with a "Post Your Answer" button. Once you post it, you can mark your answer as the official one.